# APNS not working with jdk 1.7

Tags: tomcat7, apple-push-notifications, ubuntu-12.04, java-7

Why Apple push notification server (server side) not working with jdk 1.7? I am getting **com.notnoop.exceptions.NetworkIOException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown**. I have tried the same code with jdk 1.6 and it is working perfectly fine.I am using ubuntu 12.04 and tomcat 7.
Any help would be appriciated.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java 7 (JDK 1.7) doesn't know about the Entrust Root CA.  Import your APNS cert, key, AND the Entrust CA Root certificate into a p12 file.  Point the code at that file and it will work.